# How to check, whether the user has pressed done button on iphone using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application created using `Reactjs` and in the application,i have a form when a user presses done or return button on `iOs` device i want to submit that function.As i tried but it's only working when user presses return button.

```
function Counter() {
    const [otp,setOTp]=useState('')
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
//    conform alert
        var r = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
        if (r === true) {
            alert("Submitted");
        } else {
            alert("Cancelled");
        }
        
}
  return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" value={otp} onChange={(e)=>setOTp(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q2g7.png)

Comment: You have to check if enter has been pressed with key down handler

Comment: @KonradLinkowski : As i tried it's not working

Comment: So you made it wrong, because that's how you do it. Show us the code.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski : the code is already there
`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" value={otp} onChange={(e)=>setOTp(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>`

Comment: `onKeyDown={({ key }) => key === 'Enter' && alert(1) }`